# Getting data from Firebase Database with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve data from a Firebase Database.

I have initialized my **server.js** like this:

```
var http = require("http");

var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(port);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "datatable-18f93.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "datatable-18f93",
  storageBucket: "datatable-18f93.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "282475200118"
};
const db = firebase.initializeApp(config);
app.use("/v1", routerProj);

console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
module.exports.db = db.database(); //this doesnt have to be database only
```

Then in my **router.js** I define my get route as follows:

```
var express = require("express"); // call express
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/restau");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
  });
module.exports = router;
```

In Postman with get request to this adress: `http://localhost:8080/v1` I get this error:

> Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

But I have initialized database connection in **server.js**, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you only need Firebase Admin SDK for initialization, referring to

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

and the process goes like :

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json'); // Or your config object as above.

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), // Or credential
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

Comment: It's the samething that I have made. 
Adding `var admin = require('firebase-admin');` to server.js does not solve the problem. I think that `router.js` does not read the database initialization on `server.js`

Comment: then why don't export const db = firebase.initializeApp(config); and import in router.js and use it generically

Comment: Thank I was confusing between firebase add to project configuration and Admin SDK . So I added as you mentioned and it's working

Comment: There is another issue here. That's on memory leakage. Suppose I am calling a route (with a ref.on() function called inside) 10 times. Then every time I will need to call ref.off(). Unless it can cause memory leakage!( source: [here]('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210946/firebase-realtime-database-once-vs-on/59211006#comment104639904_59211006')). Any suggestions how to fix this?