# firebase realtime database once vs on?

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using firebase realtime database on node js like database for API.

What's the different between `once()` and `on()`?

My code with `once()` work very slowly.

What is it needed for `off()`?

Example

```
router.get('/:qrid', async(req, res)=>{
    let id = req.params.qrid;
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('/qr/'+id);
    let snapshot = await ref.once('value');
    res.json(Object.assign({}, snapshot.val()));
});
```

This work very slowly (250ms-3000ms). When I use on() it all faster.

```
router.get('/:qrid',(req, res)=>{
    let id = req.params.qrid;
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('/qr/'+id);
    ref.on('value',(snapshot) => res.json(Object.assign({}, snapshot.val())));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

once:

> `once(eventType: EventType, successCallback?: function, failureCallbackOrContext?: function | Object | null, context?: Object | null): Promise<DataSnapshot>`
>
> Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening.
>
> This is equivalent to calling `on()`, and then calling `off()` inside the callback function. See on() for details on the event types.

on:

> `on(eventType: EventType, callback: function, cancelCallbackOrContext?: Object | null, context?: Object | null): function`
>
> Listens for data changes at a particular location.
>
> This is the primary way to read data from a Database. Your callback will be triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes. Use `off( )` to stop receiving updates.

`off()` is used to detach a callback previously attached with `on()`

You can check the reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html

Comment: I read doc, but this is not answer for my question. For API i should use off()?If I never use off() my node js server wil allways connect to firebase and requests wil be faster?

Comment: No the request won't be faster if u don't use `off() `. `off()` is normally used when leaving a page to unsubsribe the listener and avoid memory leaks